# cannot view web page response on Android HttpRequestHandler

Tags: android, http, service, view

I was following the tutorial on 
http://www.integratingstuff.com/2011/10/24/adding-a-webserver-to-an-android-app/

I did some copy paste, and I tried to view my page in a browser on my tablet. I have a simple activity that has 2 buttons for starting and stopping the serice for Http. Here is my code for the service:

```
package com.example.httpserver;

import java.io.IOException;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class WebService extends Service {

    private WebServer server = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Toast.makeText(this, "The new Service was Created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        server = new WebServer(this);
        server.startServer();


    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        server.stopServer();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Service Destroyed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        super.onDestroy();

    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

For the WebServer class:

```
package com.example.httpserver;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.SocketException;

import org.apache.http.HttpException;
import org.apache.http.impl.DefaultConnectionReuseStrategy;
import org.apache.http.impl.DefaultHttpResponseFactory;
import org.apache.http.impl.DefaultHttpServerConnection;
import org.apache.http.params.BasicHttpParams;
import org.apache.http.protocol.BasicHttpContext;
import org.apache.http.protocol.BasicHttpProcessor;
import org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestHandlerRegistry;
import org.apache.http.protocol.HttpService;
import org.apache.http.protocol.ResponseConnControl;
import org.apache.http.protocol.ResponseContent;
import org.apache.http.protocol.ResponseDate;
import org.apache.http.protocol.ResponseServer;

import android.content.Context;

public class WebServer  {
    public static int PORT = 8080;
    public static boolean RUNNING = false;

    private static final String ALL_PATTERN = "*";
    private static final String EXCEL_PATTERN = "/*.xls";
    private static final String HOME_PATTERN = "/home.html";

    private Context context = null;

    private ServerSocket serverSocket;
    private Socket clientSocket;
    private PrintWriter out;
    private BufferedReader in;

    private BasicHttpProcessor httpproc = null;
    private BasicHttpContext httpContext = null;
    private HttpService httpService = null;
    private HttpRequestHandlerRegistry registry = null;

    public WebServer(Context context) {
        setContext(context);
        httpproc = new BasicHttpProcessor();
        httpContext = new BasicHttpContext();

        httpproc.addInterceptor(new ResponseDate());
        httpproc.addInterceptor(new ResponseServer());
        httpproc.addInterceptor(new ResponseContent());
        httpproc.addInterceptor(new ResponseConnControl());

        httpService = new HttpService(httpproc, new DefaultConnectionReuseStrategy(), new DefaultHttpResponseFactory());
        registry = new HttpRequestHandlerRegistry();

        registry.register(HOME_PATTERN, new HomeCommandHandler(context));

        httpService.setHandlerResolver(registry);
    }

    public void runServer() {
        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(PORT);

            serverSocket.setReuseAddress(true);

            while (RUNNING) {
                try {
                    final Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();

                    DefaultHttpServerConnection serverConnection = new DefaultHttpServerConnection();

                    serverConnection.bind(socket, new BasicHttpParams());

                    httpService.handleRequest(serverConnection, httpContext);

                    serverConnection.shutdown();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (HttpException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            serverSocket.close();
        } catch (SocketException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        RUNNING = false;
    }

    public synchronized void startServer() {
        RUNNING = true;
        runServer();
    }

    public synchronized void stopServer() {
        RUNNING = false;
        if (serverSocket != null) {
            try {
                serverSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public Context getContext() {
        return context;
    }

    public void setContext(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

}
```

For the HomeCommandHandler:

```
package com.example.httpserver;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpException;
import org.apache.http.HttpRequest;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.entity.ContentProducer;
import org.apache.http.entity.EntityTemplate;
import org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext;
import org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestHandler;

import android.content.Context;


public class HomeCommandHandler implements HttpRequestHandler {

    private Context context = null;

    public HomeCommandHandler(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void handle(HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response,
        HttpContext httpContext) throws HttpException, IOException {
        HttpEntity entity = new EntityTemplate(new ContentProducer() {
            public void writeTo(final OutputStream outstream) throws IOException {
                OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(outstream, "UTF-8");
                String resp = "<html><head></head><body><h1>Home<h1><p>This is the homepage.</p></body></html>";

                writer.write(resp);
                writer.flush();
            }
        });
        response.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/html");
        response.setEntity(entity);
    }

    public Context getContext() {
        return context;
    }

}
```

I installed this application in my tablet, I started the service and then I went to my browser and typed `http://127.0.0.1:8080/home.html` but page not found. Where and How am I doing this wrong?